# python UnicodeEncodeError on startup and not able to run any script

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-idle

When I startup my python I get the following error:

*** Python 2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:03:49) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32. ***

> > > UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)

*** Remote Python engine  is active ***

> > > UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)

I currently have python 2.7 installed but this problem also appears when using the portable version. IDLE of the portable version runs without a problem but I am more used to the pyscripter environment.

Does anyone know how to get rid of this error?

-René

Comment: How do you start python? Are you running a program? If so what?

Comment: I only start the python environment. This error immediatly opens in the terminal.

Comment: Various suggestions: use 3.4 (seriously); use latest 2.7.8 (or 2.7.9rc); delete contents of <home directory)/.idlerc; post traceback leading up to error so we can see code that fails.

Comment: I've reinstalled python and made sure it was version 2.7.8. Without running any program the error above occurs. I am bound to version 2.7 due to different libraries used. Python versien 2.7 is used on my university.